# Update to Windows 8.1 without using Windows Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, windows-8.1

I am currently using Windows 8 on my desktop PC.
I want to upgrade to Windows 8.1.
I heard that Microsoft provides this update through Microsoft Store for free.
But in My home I don't have a faster internet connection.
I downloaded a Windows 8.1 ISO from cafe, but when I started installing, it asks for a key.
I typed my original Key for windows 8, but it didn't work.

Is there any way for me to update to Windows 8.1 without an internet connection and without purchasing another key?

**After I upgrade to windows 8.1 using store, if I retrieved the key using any key finding tools, will it be a new key, and will it work with new installation of windows 8.1?**

Thank you

Comment: I have Googled your quandary: http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-81-upgrade-woes

Comment: Thank you for your help. but it not saying any solution for my problem. What can I do to make it happen? there must be some files on their servers to download it for MS Store, right? How I can get it?

Comment: [From the comments](http://www.windowsvalley.com/install-windows-8-without-product-key/)

Comment: @techie007 I dont want to download a copy of ISO, which I already did. I want to update to windows 8.1 without downloading via MS Store. I saw the comments and going to try it

Comment: I tried the ways given by @techie007 but not worked.

Comment: I have another doubt but not tried yet, After I upgrade to windows 8.1 using store, if I retrieved the key using any key finding tools, will it be a new key, and will it work with new installation of windows 8.1?

Comment: That requires a new question.